# Moving a background-position of sprite in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Context: I create a semblance of rpg and I have trouble with the animation of my character’s movement I was initially on an .animate(), but I have the impression that it is not the best solution, because I have the impression that it lacks optimization see even that I complicate my life.

Here is my code for a move to the left for example:

```js
function playerRunLeft() {
    $('.player').animate({
    }, 166, function () {
        $('.player').removeClass('a-player-moove-end')
        $('.player').addClass('a-player-moove-start')
    })
    $('.player').animate({
        delay: 166
    }, 166, function () {
        $('.player').removeClass('a-player-moove-start')
        $('.player').addClass('a-player-moove-mid')
    })
    $('.player').animate({
        delay: 332
    }, 166, function () {
        $('.player').removeClass('a-player-moove-mid')
        $('.player').addClass('a-player-moove-end')
    })
}
```

```css
.a-player-moove-start {
    background-position: 780px 0px;
}

.a-player-moove-mid {
    background-position: 715px 0px;
}

.a-player-moove-end {
    background-position: 650px 0px;
}
```

I could find different way to do all different some does not use animate other uses only CSS animation...

Wouldn’t it be better to just use the property .css() is there a property or method I haven’t found?

is that what I concerve the .animate() but am I misusing it?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/animate/.  When you call `.animate()` it adds it to an animation queue, so there's no need for `delay:`, just `$(".player").animate({..}, 166).animate({..}, 166).animate({..}, 166)`

Comment: It looks like you're getting mixed up with what `animate` does.   Animate allows you to progressively change a css property over time, eg `.animate({left:100}, 100)` to slide to a specific position, animated over 100ms.  You have nothing to animate as you're not changing any css properties - you're simply toggling a class.    In this case it looks like you would want to add a [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) in your CSS which would animate the background-position as the class is toggled

Comment: If I use the transform to modify the background-position I think I no longer need the different class but indeed it seems that I misused animate() ^^'

Comment: I think we misunderstood the class change is only used to switch from one background position to another the transform does not allow me to act on the background, but on the block itself